# MySQL query showing no results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL database, with one table that has data in it. When I run the code however, it shows no results.

```
<html><head><title>...</title></head>
<body>
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Scans`";
$result = $conn->query($sql); ?>

<table><tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Barcode</td><td>Status</td><td>Business</td></tr>

<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" .$row["Date"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Time"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Barcode"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Success"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Business"]. "</td></tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";

} else {
echo "No Results";
}

$conn->close(); ?>
</body></html>
```

Please help?
I cannot understand why...

Comment: Don't you need to connect to a specific database? I mean you specified the server and the table, but not the database, right?

Comment: Missing fourth arg in `mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database)`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding database name to Scans query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db741921215`.`Scans`";
```

That seemed to work!

Comment: Yeah. Its because db is not specified in Conn

Comment: Yay, hit, sunk. I would also specify the database when connecting so you don't have to include it in every different SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, guys! Appreciate it.